# firefox svg.getElementById('id')

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg

I'm experimenting with interactive images. I've a jquery-ui slider bound to a function which updates the path inside an svg document (embedded in a web page).

I'm trying to retrieve the path with:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].getElementById('me').setAttribute('d', "M 30 30 ...)
```

This is working fine in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox (where I have to use `getElementsByClassName(..)[0]`. Is there something I'm missing, or is `id` as attribute not allowed in an svg document?

BTW I checked on the last release of Firefox 8.0

Just saw now an message in the console:

`Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsIDOMSVGSVGElement.getElementById]`

Would have been nice if this was indicated as a normal script error.

As per first comment (i'm using id's the proper way):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="370"  width="400" baseProfile="full" viewbox="0 0 1000 1000">

  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="8" fill="black" transform="scale(4)">
  <path id="me" d="" class="classme"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Perhaps the following link helps? http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=94475

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just implemented `svg.getElementById` in Firefox. It will appear in Firefox 11.

Comment: Well that's support! Just 2 hours after a filing a complaint with Firefox. Thanks a lot! Not sure how long Firefox 11 will take but in the current pace I guess it is around 9 months?

Comment: @drjerry https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar has the future release dates.  Firefox 11 would be March 13, 2012, about 18 weeks from now: the development cycle for that just started yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont mind using jQuery, I have just tested with version 1.7.1 and svg dom traversal seems to work just perfectly:

```
$("svg:first").find("#me").attr("d", "M 30 30 ...");
```

Answer (score 2):

Element nodes don't have `getElementById` method. This is understandable as ID should be unique across the whole document. Use `document.getElementById('me')`.

Note that Firefox doesn't support `getElementById` even on HTML elements (means that no common method `Element.prototype.getElementById` exists; there's just `HTMLDocument.prototype.getElementById`).

Comment: This is correct except for the fact that Firefox supports getElementById perfectly well.

Comment: @RobinBerjon Indeed, but it has just `document.getElementById`. No common method `Element.prototype.getElementById` exists in Firefox.

Comment: I almost forgot why jquery is such a great tool. Must check whether it will also work with svg elements.