# getElementById() is not working after modifying the SVG Document

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have a SVG document; say as below:

```
<svg>
   <g ...>
      <rect id="perm1" ../>
      <rect id="temp1" ../>
</svg>
```

in the run-time, I am changing the id of the second 'rect' from 'temp1' to 'calc_id1' using java script functions (see below); but immediately after modifying it, I am calling another function in which I am trying to retrieve the rect element using getElementById() with the new id 'calc_id1'; but it is returning null. I am not sure, what's wrong here but I can confirm that the rect element is updated with the new id. Any clue or answer will be of great help to me.

Please note that I am using IE9.

```
changeID( xmlDoc, "//g[@id='temp1']", "calc_id1");

function changeID( xmlDoc, xPath, newIdValue ) {
    var node = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode(xPath);
    if (node!=null){
            var oAttr = node.attributes.getNamedItem( "id");
            if (oAttr!=null){
                 oAttr.text = newIdValue;
            }
            return node;
    }
    else {
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the javascript code snippet that sets the id, just to confirm that there's nothing wrong with that bit.

Comment: added the required java script functions!

Comment: I think there should be a typo error. It should have been
changeID( xmlDoc, "//rect[@id='temp1']", "calc_id1");

Comment: thats typo in the question, in the actual code, I do have it as "//rect[id]='temp1']". I could get all the elements using getElementsByTagName() and filter the list by 'id' attribute! probably a bug in IE9!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065229/firefox-svg-getelementbyidid

Comment: @dr jerry, I am not using FF; With IE9, getElementById works only for the nodes that are loaded from .svg files; is not working the modified nodes or nodes that added during runtime; in fact, I added new <rect id="calc_id2"> element; found it using getElementsByTagName() but it is returned as a '[object Element]' where as I expected it to be a '[object SVGRECT]' :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that getElementById() did not find the newly added elements because they were not recognized as svg element; they were missing the svg namespace in it. Once I added the namespace, it worked. Pleas see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281902/in-ie9-imported-nodes-do-not-seem-to-be-recognized-as-svg-elements/9290678#9290678) for more details.