# In IE9, Imported nodes do not seem to be recognized as SVG Elements

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-9

I am adding couple of  elements into the existing SVG document using the importNode() method; everything seems to be fine; could get the newly added elements using getElementsByTagName [[getElementById() is not working]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231367/getelementbyid-is-not-working-after-modifying-the-svg-document) but the problem is that the imported elements are not getting recognized as SVGGElements instead they are mentioned just as [object Element]s. any idea guys?

Comment: Are the nodes in the SVG namespace?

Comment: @ Robert, I had the new <g> elements in an xml file like <g id='top> <g>...</g><g>...</g></g>; parsed them in to documnet using DOMParser and imported them using the importNode() method in IE9. Where can I specify the SVG namespace?

Comment: so, a <g> element is the root element in that xml file? does it have `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` specified on the root element?

Comment: yes @ErikDahlström, <g> is the root element; xmlns: nope, it does not have to have xmlns in it because it does not work on its own; it always gets inserted into a bigger svg; will try adding xmlns to see if it works

Comment: @ErikDahlström, it worked; the newly added <g> has been recognized as [object SVGGElement> but hitting at some other places since I am still in the middle of my work! Please add your comment as answer so that I can mark it as answer!

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811116/ie-support-for-dom-importnode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements inside an xml file need to define what namespace they're in, otherwise they'll get parsed as unknown xml elements.

This is true even if the root of the xml file was an <svg> element. To make sure that the elements get parsed as proper svg elements, you should add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` and possibly `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink` (if you use xlink attributes anywhere in the file).

If on the other hand you parsed the elements using an html5 parser, the constraints are similar but slightly different since xmlns attributes aren't recognized in html (only in xhtml). You'd need at least an <svg> element root for the markup to get parsed as svg in such a case, and you'd need to make sure that the markup is detected as html5 (avoiding any browser-specific legacy fallback modes). So you couldn't have a <g> element as the root if you use an html5 parser.